# getBearing not working Using KML to drive DDMS

Tags: android, ddms, locationlistener

I've been successfully using a KML file and DDMS to drive my app testing that uses LocationListener.  So far I've just been using latitude and longitude which works well.  But now I'm trying to use .getBearing and it's always returing 0.0 !!

Is this a bug in LocationListener?  Is it a bug in DDMS?
thanks, Gary